# Detecting new visitors to website without using cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies

We are looking to create a website that displays information to all new visitors to a site, i.e. welcome, please read our help guide, etc.

The big problem is that our website is not allowed to use long-lasting cookies (i.e. over 20 minutes). Does anybody know of any way we can determine whether a user has visited the site before or not. As another restriction, we can not add anyform of registration to the system.

The application is being created in ASP.Net 3.5.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EFF has a tool/site that you can visit that shows how with the plugins, OS details, browser details, etc. you can determine a visit fairly uniquely.  It could give some insight on details to store in a database to determine if the user had been there before:

https://panopticlick.eff.org/

You could attempt to use an IP address, but with NAT'ing and most ISPs handing out dynamic IP addresses anyways, you'll never really know if the user visiting is one who's been there before or not with any certainty.

Comment: +1: that's amazing. I'd be curious how often that info changes; For example I'm using Opera, with it's auto-update facility the user agent would change often. Other parts of that info look pretty stable (time zone, screen resolution). I tested with Opera, IE, Firefox and Chrome, for all 4 of them it told me "the fingerprint is unique".

Comment: Yes, it's a little scary actually if you are concerned about privacy.  Like you said though, if you change the settings often enough you will always appear different.  Or if you mask enough of the settings, you will appear like (hopefully) a lot of other users.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no way of storing information on the client side, this is impossible except for saving IPs and comparing those, which isn't really accurate either.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know of any way we can determine whether a user has visited the site before or not.

No, you can't. Since you can't use cookies all you've got is what the client's sending by default: IP address, user agent information. With the current IPv4 depletion and the popularity of NAT devices the IP is anything but useful.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way is to capture the IP address of web browser and use that as a unique ID - assuming that it is indeed unique.

Comment: Hi, this was my thinking, however like you said, there will be an overlap in users and their IP address.

Comment: Overlap? You're being optimistic. How about 'Carrier Grade NAT'. How about 3G networks with fast connect-disconnet (where you might get the IP someone else used 5 minutes ago).

Comment: -1: At least in Germany, nearly everyone using normal DSL has a new IP address every 24 hours.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't quite appreciate the 'overlap' - one of the network guys here has just explained how the NAT works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the IP since it can be shared by many user, or change for one user.

If you can't store a cookie on the client side, it is not possible.

You can also ask him: "Did you ever visited this site in the past?", but I doubt this is good practice :D

Answer (score 0):

Store a boolean value like "AlreadyVisited" in the Session. So everytime the user visits the page for the first time, he will see your welcome message.

After displaying, set the boolean to false (you need to store it in the session)